# PyQt window not closing

Tags: python, pyqt

I am learning how to use PyQt4 and I seem to have created a simple program that opens a second window when a button in the first window is clicked. My problem is that I would like the first window to close as the second one opens. I have used the `self.close()` function in the click event to no avail. I need help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'uitest.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        MainWindow.resize(288, 242)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 171, 101))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        ####################################################################################
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.ChangeUi)
        ########################################################################
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 288, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NEXT", None))

    def ChangeUi(self):

        self.newUser = Ui_MainWindow1()
        self.newUser.show()


class Ui_MainWindow1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow1):
        MainWindow1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow1"))
        MainWindow1.resize(480, 265)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 70, 111, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        MainWindow1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow1)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 480, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow1.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow1)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow1)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow1):
        MainWindow1.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow1", "MainWindow", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow1", "IT WORKED", None))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I edited your post to add a `python` tag (next to the `pyqt` tag), so that all the code in the thread would be imbued with python syntax highlighting, which makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

1) You are doing something funky here:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I change the code as below, the first window closes:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    #MainWindow.show()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2) This code:

```
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
```

calls setupUi() twice because creating a Ui_MainWindow instance causes setupUi() to be called:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.setupUi(self)
```

3) Your converted .ui file looks screwy:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
```

My converted .ui files have a class like that (Qt 4.8.6), but the class inherits from object--not QtGui.QMainWindow, which means my class is not a widget class, it's just a regular class that contains a bunch of data and some methods for creating widgets.  Did you change that?  Perhaps in response to the error: `AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'close'`?

I don't think you should be meddling with your converted .ui file.  Instead, create a different file for your code and import the converted .ui file, i.e. the .py file, and you can call the methods defined in there.  That allows you to make changes in Qt Designer, then convert the altered .ui file to a .py file again--without having to change anything in your program file.  And, doing that would have prevented you from making the mistake you did.

What follows is a simplified example consisting of a window with a button that closes the window.  The same error you made will prevent the window in this app from closing. But with your code in a separate file from the converted .ui file, look what happens:

design.py (no changes made to this converted .ui file):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(568, 409)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 150, 110, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 568, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close window", None))
```

main.py(create this file for your code):

```
import sys
import design
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMainWindow, QApplication

class MyWindow(QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()


app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that because you create only one window, you can't show the wrong window. Also, if you decide to change the .ui file (and then covert it again to a .py file) the only thing that will change is the code *inside* the functions, and because main.py only calls the functions you won't need to make any changes to main.py.

Because MyWindow inherits from the Ui_MainWindow class defined in design.py, all the widgets assigned to self in that class are accessible inside the MyWindow class using self.widgetName--when widgetName isn't found in the MyWindow class, its parent classes are searched for widgetName.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. it works well and has improved my understanding

Comment: @AK27, Wel....I posted three different explanations describing why your window wouldn't close, and I deleted them all because they proved to be wrong after further testing.  I really can't explain why changing `MainWindow.show()` to `ui.show()` succeeds--which has diminished my understanding. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was not closing every component in the window (QWidget) before closing the window itself.

I had a ScrollArea, so I had to change my code from:

```py
def close_window(self):
    self.close()
```

to:

```py
def close_window(self):
    self.scrollArea.close()

    self.close()
```

Now, the widget closes correctly.